# OSX/Clang version of __progname to get absolute path of executable?

Tags: c, macos, clang

I need to get the absolute path of a C program being executed from within a dynamic link library, running on OSX 10.9.5 with `clang` version 600.0.57.

I inherited the following library code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

extern char *__progname ;

char            *
getexecname ()
{
    return __progname ;
}
```

which is close, however `__progname` returns only the base name of the program, not the full path.

`argv[0]` is not available since this is in a library. Linux/GCC apparently has `__progname_full`, however that doesn't seem to be available for OSX/`clang`. Linux-style tricks such as `readlink()` on *'/proc/self/exe'* don't work on the Mac.

Is there a companion macro to `__progname` that gives the full pathname of the executable, and if so what is it?

As an aside, where is the `__progname` macro defined and documented?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will `_NSGetExecutablePath` work for you?